# Argument #2 is not an array

Tags: php

I can't imagine what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm getting `Argument #2 is not an array` when I try to merge two arrays. Argument #2 most certainly is an array, but PHP feels differently. Here's as specific as I can get with the code. `$bigKeys` and `$littleKeys` are pulled from the database, so I don't know if they're null or not. So I check! I have:

```
return array_merge(
  $bigKeys ? $bigKeys : array(),
  $littleKeys ? $littleKeys : array()
);
```

Now the thing is, in the case I'm testing, `$littleKeys` is `NULL`, therefore it should end up being an empty array according to the ternary I have there.

```
gettype($littleKeys ? $littleKeys : array()); // This returns "array"
```

So what in the world is going on?

Comment: What if $bigKeys = true? You're not checking that they're arrays at all. Only that they exist in some fashion.

Comment: What does `var_dump($littleKeys);` show you?

Comment: `var_dump($littleKeys);` before the ternary returns `NULL`

Comment: Well I know that they're either going to be `NULL` or an array. So the ternary should do the rest of the work. `$bigKeys` will never equal true.

Comment: ....yet here we are staring at an error indicating otherwise.

Comment: How would `$bigKeys` not throw Argument #1 is not an array, instead of Argument #2?

Comment: I have no idea, you choose to hide that portion of the code from us.

Answer (score 3):

I'd change the code to:

```
return array_merge(
    is_array($bigKeys) ? $bigKeys : array(),
    is_array($littleKeys) ? $littleKeys : array()
);
```

As if your variable (`$bigKeys` or `$littleKeys`) is in example a string, `true`, or whatever, it evaluates to true. So you can't be sure an array is passed to the `array_merge()` function. This will most probably fix your problem as well (as quite gently I don't believe there is some crazy bug in the `array_merge` function ;))